# Regarding passing a string through a Get and Set Method

Tags: c++, string

I am working on a project that asks the user to input a string, and then through get and set functions simply displays the string. However I am having issues actually having the user input the string and then pass those to the get and set functions. Here is my code:
This is  my Main.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Laptop.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Laptop Brand;
    string i;
    cout << "Enter your brand of laptop : ";
    cin >> i;
    Brand.setbrand (i);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my Laptop.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Laptop.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void Laptop::setbrand(string brand)
    {
        itsbrand = brand;
    }

string Laptop::getbrand()
    {
        return itsbrand;
    }
```

and this is my laptop.h :

```
#include<string>
class Laptop
{
private :
    string itsbrand;

public :
    void setbrand(string brand);
    string getbrand();

};
```

In my laptop.cpp I have errors with setbrand and getbrand. They say that getbrand and setbrand are incompatible . I am pretty sure it has to do with I am passing a string through the parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the exact errors and lines? Also, it's generally better to pass `std::string` by const reference and to make member functions that don't modify the object const. As for the error, the header needs `std::string`, not `string` as it is. I don't know whether that's the error you describe, though.

Comment: Also get brand should have this signature: `string getbrand() const`.

Comment: @MikeD, `int` stops at whitespace and `std::string` stops at whitespace. What's the difference?

Comment: @MikeD, Yeah, but `54 65` only reads 54 for an `int`. There's no semantic difference imo. I'd rephrase it to "reading a string with `cin >>` stops at whitespace."

Comment: I have been trying to pass the string to the setbrand function using :

Comment: setbrand(cin,i) but its not working very well. It keeps telling me I have too many paramaters. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The good fix here is to use `std::string` instead of `string` in the header file:

```
class Laptop
{
private :
    std::string itsbrand;

public :
    void setbrand(std::string brand);
    std::string getbrand();
};
```

unlike the other files you do not have `using namespace std`. I would actually suggest just using `std::string` everywhere. It is safer and will save you from worse problems later on.

Comment: Don't ever suggest putting "using namespace" in a header. It won't kill the programmer to type "std::" in front of his string variables and method parameters. Tracking down using bugs will waste far more time than the time take to just type your namespaces explicitly.

Comment: @jmucchiello You are indeed correct, it just be discouraged period, amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to include the correct namespace in the `laptop.h` file therefore the compiler cannot find any declared `string` class in the current (global) namespace. Just put, in the beginning of the file, `using std::string;`.

On a side note I'd avoid generic

```
using namespace std;
```

because it fights the purpose of having namespaces in the first place. It's usually better to specify exactly what kind of class you are using. Therefore:

```
using std::string;
```

is better.

Comment: Thank you Jueecy that helped a lot.